# Android-Logger by noveogroup does not pick up configuration

Tags: android, logging

I'm switching to the Android-Logger from noveo-group and having problems. It appears that the android-logger.properties file is not being picked up by the library and as a result I get very verbose log statements. I have placed it in the **src/** directory as the directions [on the homepage indicate](https://noveogroup.github.io/android-logger/).

Here is the file I am using:

`root=INFO:MyApp`

Just one line and here is the resulting log statement:

> 02-21 12:27:44.967 2732-2732/com.test.myapp
>   I/com.test.myapp.MediaPlayer: 2017-02-21 12:27:44.966
>   org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerAdapter#log:55
>                                                                                             test message

whereas I would expect something like:

> 02-21 12:27:44.967 2732-2732/com.test.myapp I/MyApp: test message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the homepage is out of date. It lists 1.3.1 as the latest release when in fact, 1.3.6 is the most current version. In addition to that, placement of the logging file in the src directory is incorrect. It needs to be located in the **src/main/resources** folder to work.

The documentation [on the github page](https://github.com/noveogroup/android-logger) is correct, though somewhat spartan.